# Running the web page in mongod

Tags: php, mongodb, netbeans-8

Been working with the WAMP and SQL, now I'm moving on to Mongodb. So how could I run and see my page as localhost in mongod. I have already configured the the netbeans with Nbmongo. Is it possible for me to work the same way as WAMP in mongod as well?
Please direct me!

Comment: do you want to work with php and mongodb..?

Comment: yes and work with mongod as local host @chirag

Comment: then refer this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm